# Android Searchview on Firebase Data

Tags: android, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

I want to implement the Android Searchview function in a listview fragment populated with data from a Firebase Database.

Code to get the Firebase Data

```
 mPOIAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Poi>(
            getActivity(),
            Poi.class,
            R.layout.item_layout_poi,
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("poi").orderByChild("name")) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Poi model, int position) {
            TextView pointsText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.poi_textview);
            pointsText.setText(model.getName());
            TextView pointDescr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.poi_building);
            pointDescr.setText(model.getDescription());
        }
    };

    mPOIListView.setAdapter(mPOIAdapter);
```

Searchview code :

```
   @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    item.setVisible(true);
    SearchView searchView =  (SearchView) item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I want to use code like this to filter the Listview items based on the input of the users

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        getListAdapter().getFilter().filter(s);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Because the FirebaseListAdapter doesn't have the same possibilities as the ListAdapter, i can't use the `getListAdapter().getFilter().filter(s)`

Is there an alternative way to use the search function in a Listview fragment populated with Firebase Data

Comment: hii brent, i have same issue. did you find any solution? if yes plz update your answer here. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need in any array just create new method "firebaseUserSearch"
the copy your RecyclerView adapter and paste inside. use you databaseReference to filter it.

My FB structure is :

```
 BLABLA:
     Bars:
         01: 
            BarName: "Best bar"
         02:
            BarName: "The Worst bar"
```

And code is here:

```
  ....

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference ("Bars");

  .....


  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String searchText) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchText) {

            searchText = searchView.getQuery().toString();

            firebaseUserSearch (searchText);

            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}



private void firebaseUserSearch (final String searchText) {


    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Bar, ViewHolder>(

            Bar.class,
            R.layout.custom_row,
            ViewHolder.class,
       databaseReference.orderByChild("barName").startAt(searchText.toUpperCase()).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff"))
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Bar model, final int position) {

  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("poi").orderByChild("name").equalTo("anyName")) {
```

try this **orderByChild("name").equalTo("nameString")**

it'll check if there is any matched name belongs to name child. if there is any it'll show that to list